# Name of fantasy book with Monster Under the Bed

Tags: story-identification

I read a fantasy book long ago, about a kid who rode a monster under the bed as his steed. It was made out of dust, and was semi-sentient. I've been looking for several years for this book, with no luck. I've gone through several search engines using all the permutations I can think of.

I didn't think it would be this hard to find it!

Comment: Can you quantify "long ago" at all?  Even just to a decade?

Comment: Long ago = about 12 years ago.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Princess Ivy is the origin of [Snortimer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Other_characters_of_Xanth#Snortimer), the monster under the bed, in Piers Anthony's Xanth series.  I believe he was introduced in [Dragon on a Pedestal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_on_a_Pedestal).

However, iirc it was Grundy the Golem who actually rode Snortimer in Golem in the Gears.